# CSV Helper parser throw IOException. Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, csv, azure

I'm using CSVHelper in my c# project and reading a big csv data file (about 2000 records) into memory.

https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

it works fine if the records are under 500, it always throw me IOException on different stage depends on the network or if the number goes up. I currently deployed to the Azure cloud platform, so the reading from blob storage to server, that shouldn't be any network problem.

```
CsvHelper.CsvParserException: A parsing error occurred.

Row: '995' (1 based)
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at CsvHelper.CsvParser.GetChar(Int32& fieldStartPosition, Int32& rawFieldStartPosition, String& field, Boolean prevCharWasDelimiter, Int32& recordPosition, Int32& fieldLength, Boolean isPeek) in c:\Projects\CsvHelper\src\CsvHelper\CsvParser.cs:line 445
   at CsvHelper.CsvParser.ReadLine() in c:\Projects\CsvHelper\src\CsvHelper\CsvParser.cs:line 247
   at CsvHelper.CsvParser.Read() in c:\Projects\CsvHelper\src\CsvHelper\CsvParser.cs:line 108
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CsvHelper.CsvParser.Read() in c:\Projects\CsvHelper\src\CsvHelper\CsvParser.cs:line 136
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.Read() in c:\Projects\CsvHelper\src\CsvHelper\CsvReader.cs:line 173
```

it throws on while (csv.read())

```
 var wc = new WebClient();

            using (var sourceStream = wc.OpenRead(fileUrl))
            {

                using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(sourceStream)))
                {


                    while (csv.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {

//some reading operation
}
 catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            _logger.Error(ex);
                        }
                    }
                    _logger.InfoFormat("Finished {0} reading data #{1}");

                }
            }
```

Anywhere to set streamreader timeout value?

Comment: Just a thought but like so many other things in Azure, should you have some retry logic around `csv.Read()` to handle transient errors? Also, if you really think there are network-triggered issues (other than rare events, I'd doubt that's truly the source of your issues), then you could/should grab the file and cache it on the local drive as quickly as possible, then stream from there.

Comment: you mean copy the file from blob storage to local server and parse it from there?

Comment: yes. Copy locally and then parse it. Or just copy to local Memory, no need to save it, but make sure you have the whole content first.

Answer (score 2):

When working with Cloud resources (be it Azure or any other Cloud Resource) you should not read directly a file. At best you should implement retry logic to make sure you bypass any transient errors (read about Transient errors [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/05/22/dealing-with-windows-azure-storage-transient-faults.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh851746.aspx) and [there](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-troubleshooting/) or just search the Internet about the term "Transient Error").

In your case I suggest that you wrap your calls aroud the [CloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtostream%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) method. Thus, you can still use the Stream to parse the file, but you will also work behind the security of the .NET Azure Blob API library which takes care of all transient errors on your behalf.

Your code would look something like this:

```
// get the CloudblockBlob object
using(MemoryStream blobStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    blobObject.DownloadToStream(blobStream);
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(blobStream)))
    {
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            try
            {
             //some reading operation
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
        _logger.InfoFormat("Finished {0} reading data #{1}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that, and have implemented this as a temp solution. Though the answer I'm looking for, is why this happens ? Why does azure of (WCF) think it can close the connection ? 

And is there a way (or a streamReader implementation) that would handle such kind of error, out of the box ?

Comment: Like - read, if broken, save the position, and reopen the connection, seek to the last point, and continue reading

Comment: I have provided 3 links to understand what is Transient error and why they happen. Try to read the answer, read the references and then ask new questions ...